# Valid assertions for cubing program

Tags: java, cube, assertion

I need to provide some assertions for a simple input cubing program. Basically the assertions I have provided don't seem to cooperate with the program. I've tried simplifying statements to true/false, but as expected this doesn't solve anything, and ultimately creates more problems. (This is done on Java 8)

Here is the code in question

```
public static int cube(int n) {
          int cube = 0, threeNsquared = 0, threeN = 0;

          int i = 0;
        assert threeNsquared == i*i*i : threeNsquared;
        assert threeN == 3*i : threeN;
          while (i < n) {
            assert threeNsquared == i*i*i : threeNsquared;
            assert threeN == 3*i : threeN;
              cube = cube + threeNsquared + threeN + 1;
              assert threeNsquared == (i+1)*(i+1)*(i+1);
              assert threeN == 3*i;
              threeNsquared = threeNsquared + 2*threeN + 3;
              threeN = threeN + 3;
              assert(threeNsquared == (i+1)*(i+1));
              assert(threeN == 3*(i + 1));
              i++;
              assert(threeNsquared == i*i*i);
              assert(threeN == 3*i);
          }
          assert threeNsquared == n*n*n : threeNsquared;
          assert threeN == 3*n;
          return cube;
    }

    /**
     * Run the cube method.
     *
     * @param args (ignored)
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = ReadInt.read("Please input a number to be cubed");
        int result = cube(x);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,x + "^3=" + result,"Function result",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Error given:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: 3
    at arithmetic.Cube.cube(Cube.java:27)
    at arithmetic.Cube.main(Cube.java:52)

Process finished with exit code 1


assert threeNsquared == (i+1)*(i+1)*(i+1);
```

This seems to be the line it takes issue with, I'm yet to find a solution. The actual process of cubing a number should be fine in theory, as before I added the assertions for clarity, it cubed any number I entered successfully. Thanks

Comment: `assert threeNsquared == i*i*i : threeNsquared;` and `assert threeNsquared == (i+1)*(i+1)*(i+1);`. You don't change either `i` or `threeNsquared` between those two statements.

Comment: `assert` is supposed to throw an `AssertionError`. Are you sure you're using it correctly?

Comment: Also, is there a requirement to not just use `n * n * n` to cube?